# jqgrid load grid on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I basically want to leave the grid blank on page load. Then based on a selection from drop down. I want to load the grid. How can I do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your `buildUrl()` function code?

Comment: @Lance, it works now, it was a syntax issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `datatype: 'local'` at the beginning. So the grid will be empty without any contain. Then you should set 'change' handler on the dropdown element. Inside of the event handler you should change the `datatype` to 'json' (or 'xml' depend on your requirements) with respect of `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', {datatype: 'local'})` and call `trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}])`. Yo can use `postData` with functions as the properties (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819)) or just set `url` parameter together with the `datatype` inside of the 'change' event handler.